# TCP IOCP won't receive after acceptex

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, iocp

I'm trying to write an IOCP server. Basically, I have it accepting new connections. For the purpose of my testing, I'm running and connecting to 127.0.0.1.

I create the pseudo socket prior to calling AcceptEx(). Once a connection is accepted, the new pseudo socket is used for communication. This new socket is associated with an io completion port [CreateIoCompletionPort], I then assign it a few options, [SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE] and [SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT], and then I call WSARecv() to accept incoming data.

The problem is that once my remote connection connects to the server, it sends data, but that data is never received. I'm wondering if someone could offer some ideas as to why it's not receiving data? Perhaps my logic is flawed? I stepped through my code several times. no errors are recorded.

EDIT: Fixed the wording. I create the socket before AcceptEx() call.

**Basic logic in my code:**

```
// Create socket, associate with IOCP
WSASocket(af, type, proto, lpProtoInfo, g, dwFlags);
HANDLE hIOCP = GetPool()->GetQueueHandle();
CreateIoCompletionPort(hSource, hIOCP, 0, 0) != NULL;

// Server bind and listen
bind(m_shSocket, pAddr, nAddrLen);
listen(m_shSocket, nBacklog);

// Creation of the pseudo socket
SOCKET s = ::WSASocket(m_iSocketAf, m_iSocketType, m_iSocketProto, m_pWpi, m_SocketGroup, m_dwSocketFlags);

DWORD dwBytes;
BOOL bRet = m_fnAcceptEx(m_shSocket, s, chOutput, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_STORAGE) + 16, sizeof(SOCKADDR_STORAGE) + 16, &dwBytes, m_pcbAccept);

// ... New Connection comes in, it's accepted ...

// Associate new pseudo socket with IOCP
HANDLE hNewIOCP = GetPool()->GetQueueHandle();
CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE) s, hNewIOCP , 0, 0) != NULL;

// ... Remote socket sends ...
// ... Remote socket and Pseudo socket call WSARecv ...
// ... Pseudo socket does not receive ...
```

NOTE: I tried sending from the pseudo socket to the remote socket, same problem as sending data in the reverse way.

Comment: You need to post your code to get answers on this

Comment: Yep... post you code please...

Sounds like You are sitting behind a firewall or missed a call or didnt bound to a well-known port on Your server... or forgot to call GetQueuedCompletionStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm an idiot. I was sending zero bytes.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to post some code but your description doesn't make sense. That's NOT how `AcceptEx()` based servers operate.

With an `AcceptEx()` based server you create your accepted socket before you post the `AcceptEx()`. You then post the `AcceptEx()` with the listening socket and the new socket and a buffer which allows you to receive the remote address and, optionally, data.

So if you are describing your code in your original question then your code is wrong or you're not using `AcceptEx()`. I'm currently ignoring the 'few options' that you throw into the mix as they simply further confuse things at present without any code to analyse.

You might be interested in downloading my [free IOCP based server framework](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html), which includes  working `AcceptEx()` and traditional `Accept()` based server code. You can get it from here: http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling [GetQueuedCompletionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364986%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the data?

In case you are not doing this just to learn for yourself, I would also recommend that you use [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) - an excellent library that allows you to let someone else do the tedious code for handling the io completion ports.